# Get first element in an array of object by index

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object :

```
this.things=[
   {
      id:XYZ, 
      event: Fri Jul 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
      person: 3
   }, {
      person: 4
      id:XYZ1, 
      event: Fri Jul 10 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
   }, {
      id:XYZ2,
      person: 5 
      event: Fri Aug 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
   }
]
```

I only want to get the first event value like this.

```
event: Fri Jul 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

tried this

```
this.things[Object.keys(this.things)[0]['event']]
```

unfortunately not working.

Comment: You're over-complicating the issue.  For the first event just use `things[0].event`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `Object.keys` here.

```
this.things[0]['event']
```

or

```
this.things[0].event
```

Comment: Come on, answering array / object access basics?

Comment: It would probably still work with the Object.keys if he put the ['event'] outside of the brackets.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    this.things = [
      {
        id: 'XYZ',
        event: 'Fri Jul 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
        person: '3'
      }, {
        person: 4,
        id: 'XYZ1',
        event: 'Fri Jul 10 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
      }, {
        id: 'XYZ2',
        person: '5 ',
        event: 'Fri Aug 20 2018 15:00:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
      }
    ]

    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.things[i].event
```

```html
Clear your Array object error "," 

 <h1 id="demo"></h1>
```